# How can I clean my lab coat?

Tags: safety

Over the course of my studies, my lab coat has absorbed a non-negligible amount of different chemicals, some of them nasty organic polymers, some are more insoluble inorganic compounds like $\ce{Cr2O3}$.

Even after washing the lab coat some stains remain. Is there a way to get rid of those, or should I rather buy a new lab coat?

Comment: Messy in the lab are we? :)  Most I ever have to deal with is coffee spills.

Comment: @LordStryker ... the perks of being in the theory department. Well, on the downside, goodbye ether...

Comment: Well, I only use my lab coat for my chemistry olympiads duties. And it really would make a better impression on the students if I didn't walk around looking like a hobo in a lab coat ;)

Comment: I think that you have have already answered your question in your last comment: If you have to wear it as a supervisor, you want a new, fresh and clean coat. The multi-coloured undergrad rag with holes from sulfuric acid spills and dirty areas on the butt - students typically wipe their hands there - will not leave the best impression ;)

Comment: Why do you want a clean lab coat?  Having a coat covered in stains, and full of holes, indicates that you've been doing real chemistry.

Comment: I am disgusted at the thought of the coffee coming anywhere close to a lab coat and I sincerely hope that this happened in the lab coat’s natural environment, not the coffee’s.

Comment: @Jan I do not know what gave you the impression that the stains on the lab coat were coffee (which they assuredly were not). The "coffee spills are trouble" come from computational chemists.

Comment: If you don't have access to a laundering service, you may want to check out disposable lab coats.  You can reuse them several times, and they come with snap closures, pockets and cuffs.  Then if you spill something? Just throw it away and grab another one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A lab coat will eventually get dirty, that's why it is a good idea to wear it. I had a lot of students complaining about the condition of their coat and they asked me if they could just wash it in the washing machine. My answer was always ***no***.

As far as I remember - I am a theoretician now - a labcoat costs much less than a pair of trousers and a T-shirt. It should be renewed annually and disposed of according to the norms how you would dispose of an unknown chemical. You never know where the chemicals incorporated in your coat will end up, so dispose of them as safely as you can.

In some countries, it is required by the employer to provide equipment like that and taking care of either cleaning or disposing of it eventually. (In Germany that should be the case.) Wear it as a disposable layer of protection and please - for the safety of the environment and yourself - do never ever put it in a normal washing machine again.

---

As an additional note, if you wash it in the same washer like your normal clothes, how can you assure that it will not end up in your everyday clothes? I can imagine, that having chromium whatever in my underwear would not make me feel alright.

Comment: Everything soluble will get diluted into oblivion, and I believe in the Swiss sewage treating plants. ;)
And actually, I had to pay quite a bit for my lab coat. It was about as expensive as a pair of jeans...

Comment: @tschoppi For heaven's sake man, it's only 17 dollars! http://www.justlabcoats.com/white-lab-coats.aspx

Comment: It's a bad idea to not wash a lab coat. You wash your fingers, hair, glassware etc., but want to wear a coat that inevitably gets contaminated with something for a year? And i don't just mean obvious colourful spills. Have your head of lab organise the washing, by all means, but if that's not possible: Put it in a cotton bag, carry that to your home washing machine, put it in there *yourself*, just the coat, and let it run at 90°C. And then find yourself a better workplace.

Comment: @ Superbest Those are crap coats. A few drops of conc. nitric acid and you're  an olympic flame with a little less media attention.

Comment: @Karl You might want to write that up as a separate answer. I disagree, that you should ever wash your lab coat yourself. I think it is negligent to take it out of a lab in some other way than a trash bag.

Comment: Well, suit yourself. I'm pretty sure that won't contaminate my washing machine, because I'm a chemist and know how detergents work. If other people neglect my safety, I rather ensure it myself instead.

Comment: @Karl If you are implying that I might not know how detergents work, then I am very sorry to disappoint you. I am very glad to hear that you care about your safety. I still think it is not a good idea to take a lab coat home, as I already stated, I do not think it is a good idea to remove it from the lab in the first place. I believe that  is negligent. But this discussion should not happen in the comments section, if you would like to continue talking about it, I can be found in [chat].

Answer (score 12):

Lab coats, like other forms of [PPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_protective_equipment), are supposed to provide a final barrier of protection, for when all other risk mitigation strategies have failed. They are not just an expensive form of a fancy cooking apron. If you are getting spills on your lab coat, you should take this as an opportunity to re-examine your laboratory techniques to try to establish why this is happening.

Contamination (including wiping hands) on lab coats should be treated at the time of incident, and contaminated lab coats should not be removed from the laboratory, unless in a contaminated laundry or waste container. Most workplaces will have a well-defined plan for laundering lab coats, and strict guidelines for how often this should be done. [You can search for just how common this is](https://www.google.com.au/?q=cleaning%20lab%20coats%20SOP#q=cleaning%20lab%20coats%20SOP).

Good lab coats can be expensive, but think of them a little like fire extinguishers. Most days in the lab, you shouldn't even need one. However, you want to make sure that when you DO need them, they will work properly and do the job they are designed for. Regular laundering of a non-contaminated lab coat will keep it in top condition, but once contaminated with hazardous chemicals that cannot be safely neutralized, they should then be replaced.

So, the answer to your question is: no, you should not attempt to launder your lab coat. Buy a new one.

And a final 2 cents worth: Dirty lab coats are not a badge of honour; they are a sign of a sloppy chemist.

Answer (score 8):

You should *never* wash your own lab coat. That defeats the whole purpose of lab coats: separating yourself from the potentially hazardous chemicals you work with.

But your employer may have a program for laundering lab coats. My university has a program for safely and properly laundering lab coats. This way you can keep it reasonably clean until replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Use or discard.  There is no "clean."  DuPont Teflon Advanced or an old can of perfluoroctanesulfonate Scotchguard for the new lab coat?  Classic Scotchguard, 
[image: classic Scotchguard]

An eaten lab coat decorated with holes, stains, and blackened smears of stopcock grease along the sides is a badge of honor.  You keep a pressed new one aside for when hominims in suits visit (JAFOs).  Formal occasions demand the Black Lab Coat.  They cannot be purchased.  As with lightsabers, you must make your own.  Given the potential toxicity of aniline black, one recommends starting with a new 100% cotton lab coat washed (remove sizing) and double rinsed.  Then, Procion MX and/or Cibacon F reactive blacks (and lots of non-iodized salt).

http://www.worlddyevariety.com/disperse-dyes/disperse-blue-354.html 
If you are a polyester sort of fellow, Foron Brilliant Blue disperse dyes.

Comment: Polyester labcoat sounds to me like 'among the top ten worst ideas'.

Comment: A polyester lab coat is a warning to others, yes.  it melts onto you.